# Implement Applicative for custom ZipList

Tags: haskell, typeclass, applicative, algebraic-data-types, custom-data-type

This comes from an exercise in book *Haskell from First Principles*. The exercise is to implement `Applicative` for `ZipList'`, which is analogous to the Prelude's `ZipList`. The book has this hint

> Check Prelude
>   for functions that can give you what you need. One starts
>   with the letter `z`, the other with the letter `r`. You’re looking
>   for inspiration from these functions, not to be able to directly
>   reuse them as you’re using a custom `List` type, not the 
>   `Prelude` provided list type.

I guessed the function that starts with `z` is `zipWith`, but I do not know about a function that starts with `r`.

```
data List a =
    Nil
  | Cons a (List a)
  deriving (Eq, Show)

zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> List a -> List b -> List c
zipWith' _ Nil _ = Nil
zipWith' _ _ Nil = Nil
zipWith' f (Cons x xs) (Cons y ys) = Cons (f x y) (zipWith' f xs ys)

newtype ZipList' a = ZipList' (List a)
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor ZipList' where
  fmap f (ZipList' xs) = ZipList' $ fmap f xs

instance Applicative ZipList' where
  pure x = ZipList' $ Cons x Nil
  (ZipList' fs) <*> (ZipList' xs) = ZipList' $ zipWith' ($) fs xs
```

This passes a test case in the book, but I am wondering if there's a better way to implement it since I did not use a function that starts with `r`. I have a feeling this was supposed to be `repeat` because it's also supposed to work over infinite lists.

Comment: Your `instance Applicative` seems to be working over a `ZipList'` type that you did not define here?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Forgot to paste that in, I updated the question

Comment: Your `pure` is incorrect, and once you've figured out the correct implementation, you will see which function beginning with `r` is being referred to. The key is to think about the requirement for a lawful `Applicative` instance that `fmap f x == (pure f) <*> x`, and recognise that there is no upper limit on the length of the list `x`. That should be enough hints for you to figure it out.

Comment: @RobinZigmond `pure 1 :: ZipList Int` creates an infinite list so that seems to be my problem, I'm trying to work out how it satisfies the law now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought about it for a bit after [Robin Zigmond's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58593349/implement-applicative-for-custom-ziplist#comment103499950_58593349):

> The key is to think about the requirement for a lawful `Applicative` instance that `fmap f x == (pure f) <*> x`, and recognise that there is no upper limit on the length of the list `x`.

This implementation should satisfy the Applicative laws.

```
data List a =
    Nil
  | Cons a (List a)
  deriving (Eq, Show)

zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> List a -> List b -> List c
zipWith' _ Nil _ = Nil
zipWith' _ _ Nil = Nil
zipWith' f (Cons x xs) (Cons y ys) = Cons (f x y) (zipWith' f xs ys)

repeat' :: a -> List a
repeat' x = Cons x $ repeat' x

newtype ZipList' a = ZipList' (List a)
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor ZipList' where
  fmap f (ZipList' xs) = ZipList' $ fmap f xs

instance Applicative ZipList' where
  pure x = ZipList' $ repeat' x
  (ZipList' fs) <*> (ZipList' xs) = ZipList' $ zipWith' ($) fs xs
```

Comment: Yes, that's it :-) You can check for yourself by comparing with the [official implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Control.Applicative.html#line-132) (it's near the bottom of the code)

Answer (score 3):

Reading the thread under the original post, I came to a conclusion the author of the post is trying to prove that the implementation satisfies the law (`fmap f xs = (pure f) <*> xs`):

Let's try proving it as a classical identity, getting rid of the wrapper. Thus, let's work with the right hand:

`(pure f) <*> xs = (repeat' f) <*> xs = zipWith' ($) (repeat' f) xs`;

As far as identity goes, proving that `zipWith' ($) (repeat' f) xs` equals `fmap f xs` would suffice.

The reason they are the same is pretty obvious:

`length (zipWith op xs ys) == min (length xs) (length ys)`; (this expression could not be evaluated in case of both `xs` and `ys` being infinite).

Since `repeat' f` is infinite, `length $ zipWith' ($) (repeat' f) xs` is, in fact, `length xs` (here, it does not actually matter, whether such a value exists: the existence of indices would suffice). Each element of `xs` gets applied to the same function `f`, which is repeated. As you can see, the size is preserved and every element is morphed by a constant function, which is the definition of `fmap`.

Comment: you can make it formal by structural induction, substituting the definitions of `zipWith`, `repeat` and `map`: `zW ($) (f:rep f) (x:xs) = (f $ x) : zW ($) (rep f) xs = (f x) : map f xs` where `zW ($) (rep f) xs == map f xs` holds by IH, and `zW ($) (rep f) [] = [] = map f []` is the base case.

Comment: @WillNess True, this is what I wanted to post originally, but what is the point since we've got all the definitions at hand? Sometimes RT-analyses could be a way more useful skill, rather than strict proof.

Comment: what is "RT" please?

Comment: @WillNess Runtime analysis. (Sorry, there should have been an 'i', not 'e', i.e. not plural).